# Combining Fields when using LIKE operator in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

OK so I am retrieving `fullname` from web page to filter customer list and I am not really sure which part is first name or last name so I need to run a similar query like the one below:

```
"SELECT sc.*, c.firstname, c.lastname,c.email FROM scoop_customer AS sc LEFT JOIN 
customer AS c ON sc.customer_id = c.customer_id WHERE c.firstname + ' ' + c.lastname 
LIKE '%".$fullname."%'"
```

But it doesn't seem working to me even though I tried many times and normally it should have been returning values from DB. Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: **WARNING** your code maybe susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Or denial of service if you search for "%" and table is big enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONCAT(c.firstname , ' ' , c.lastname )`

Answer (score 2):

Try [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
 WHERE concat(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) LIKE '%".$fullname."%'"
```

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT Would be nice for these operations

Please see the mysql doc

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

"SELECT sc.*, c.firstname, c.lastname,c.email FROM scoop_customer AS sc LEFT JOIN 
customer AS c ON sc.customer_id = c.customer_id WHERE CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($fullname)."%'"

Answer (score 1):

I'd break full name into first and last and do 2 like checks and get rid of the Wildcard % at the beginning of each.  The concatenation and the wildcard starting the like is going to break any indexing you may have on the name fields.

Of course if you only have a couple thousand customers in the table the indexing won't mater much, but when you get into the 100,000's you'll feel it!

Answer (score 1):

Asuming that you haven't escaped it previously I  have added mysql_real_escape_string.
For the question, the trick is `OR`, but not `CONCAT`

```
".... WHERE c.firstname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($fullname)."%'
         OR c.lastname  LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($fullname)."%'"
```